# Geometry Nodes avoid object

Tags: node-editor, transforms, geometry, geometry-nodes

So I have a point instance node, with the object as a cube that is scaled down to 0.001m.  I want to be able to drag an empty around the scene, and have all the cubes avoid the empty.  Is there a way to do this?  I am a visual learner, so pictures would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!
Node setup as of now, the empty controls scale.
[image: Node Setup as of now. The empty controls scale as of now.]

Comment: I like visuals too, so a screenshot showing your node setup as well as your mesh (instance mesh, and "emitter" mesh if there is one) would be helpful. I can't tell from your question whether you're instancing the cube on another mesh (without a join geometry node), or if you're instancing on an empty object (this matters because mesh vertices represent instance points).

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with this node setup:

[image]

I first calculate the direction of the cube/position by subtracting the empty's location from the position. Then i calculate the length of that vector. This i reverse this by dividing 1/distance. Then i scale my "movement" vector from my subtractions with this value.

result:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, however, is there a way to control falloff, and/or the radius of the effector?

Comment: Of course ;) ask a new question and I will help you! 

Comment: Thanks!  My new question is here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233302/control-falloff-geometry-node-setup