# Control falloff geometry node setup

Tags: node-editor, transforms, geometry, geometry-nodes

Follow-up of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233163/geometry-nodes-avoid-object/233247?noredirect)
How would I be able to control the falloff of a node setup like this?

[image: My node setup]
Currently, This does this:

[image]

I want to be able to control the falloff of a thing like this.  how would I be able to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain a falloff, you need some function of `distance from Falloff Center`, which is `1` when the distance is `0`, and `0` when the distance is `Falloff Radius`. A *Map Range* node can do this for you, and clamp its output to 0 for anything beyond the radius.

[image]

Above..

- The vector from the controlling Empty (the falloff center)  to the vertex position, is stashed as `e->p`
- The distance between them, as `p<->e`
- and the range of that distance  `0 -> Falloff Radius` is mapped to `1 -> 0`

The effect that's being faded, here, is the movement of vertices away from the Empty  (i.e. movement along `e->p`). Now we have a 0 -> 1 falloff, we can multiply that vector by a scale of the falloff, and add it to the position...

[image]

Above,  `Falloff` is also raised to a power, to provide some option in falloff's curve. You could get more control by using an *Attribute Curve Map* node instead of the *Power*, but I haven't found a way to present that curve to the user in the GN modifier.

[image]

This gif  shows  change in Radius.

[image]

This one, Power, and Scale.

[image]

Comment: You are a legend! I will be sure to credit you in the project I make with this!