# Sinusoidal damping from distance object (Wave function - Geometry Nodes)

Tags: modifiers, mathematics, geometry-nodes

I am attempting to replicate blenders wave modifier using geometry nodes but have run into a hurdle trying to implement damping(fall off), due to a limited understanding of maths.

[image]

I'm combining these two techniques to try and achieve this:

[Control falloff geometry node setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233302/control-falloff-geometry-node-setup)

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/nm8yfc/geometry_node_setup_for_procedural_wave_animation/

This is my current attempt:
[image]

The wave is working but the frame labeled "Not Sure" is the attempt at damping and it essentially does nothing.

EDIT:

After some experiments I've managed to get the damping to work as intended but it does not follow the empty.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any advise on where I've gone wrong in my graph, would be greatly appreciated as I've sunk quite a few hours into this.

Would it help if I shared the .blend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function, as graphed, is of `t`, which is [distance-to-0], (along the X axis). So we just have to substitute [distance-to-Empty] for `t`, giving ourselves the option of scaling and/or shifting it along the way:

[image]

You may want different parameters, but I think these cover all options,with the least interaction between them..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your time! These parameters should be perfect for what I'm trying to achieve. I will spend some time over the next few days trying to understand the maths behind it.

Comment: @special_frog Thanks! If you knock out all the nodes with parameters attached, the math is just the graphed expression.

Comment: As a follow up to this question... Would this same setup work with proximity information instead of location? or even having two(or more) origins in order to have interference?

Comment: 1. This already is proximity information.. it uses the distance to the empty. Perhaps you could be a bit more specific.. but  I feel if you want some more elaborate function-of -distance, that could just be an adjustment to the falloff section of the tree. 2. Sure you could have interference. Perhaps instead of _setting_ the Z position of verts, you could _add_ to the pZ. Then you could stack the modifiers. I'll have a go, if you like,

Comment: That would be great if you have the time! I will try and give it a go otherwise based off of your advice. The scene I'm trying to create is kind of abstract but is essentially built upon ripples emanating from multiple different points in varying stages of interference. I figured that using distance from geometry would be a good solution as it would solve the first problem of having multiple points and add an additional level of control that I can see being useful for other projects. Thanks again!

Comment: @special_frog I've replaced the .blend with one including a tweaked tree and an illustration of interference, using the same modifier twice, aimed at different Empties..

Comment: That works great! I think distance from geometry would produce some pretty interesting results but is an additional level of complexity that is not necessary for my current project. I will be sure to credit you once I've made something with your modifier. Many thanks, this is super helpful!