# Changing Geometry Nodes Modifier Input with Python

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes

I'm a novice with Python (at best) and fairly new to Blender, so apologies in advance for the question. Nonetheless, I have been searching all similar Qs/As online for hours and cannot find the solution.

I have a scene with a plane that is displaced in a ripple pattern according to the proximity of another object (using the geometry node modifier set-up from this excellent post: [Sinusoidal damping from distance object (Wave function - Geometry Nodes)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238869/sinusoidal-damping-from-distance-object-wave-function-geometry-nodes)). I can copy a second geometry node modifier on the plane, create a ripple pattern with a different object, and generate an interference pattern from the two, which works great. Three object version here:

[image]

The problem is that I have several hundred objects, and doing this by hand is not viable. Using a simple script I can copy and rename as many modifiers as I want, however, I cannot work out how the change the object reference. Essentially, in reference to the above image, I just need to know how to change the "Origin Object" from "Icosphere.002" to "Icosphere.003", or whatever object I want.

It looks like it should be so simple, using the following where "Input_6" is the "Origin Object" input.

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].Input_6 = "Icosphere.003"
```

But this returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NodesModifier' object has no attribute 'Input_6'
```

I can see many others have encountered this issue online, but I cannot find/do not understand the workaround. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```py
bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_6"] = bpy.data.objects["Icosphere.003"]
```

You can see it suggested when you type in console:

```py
C.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]
```

and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much! Interestingly, when I used the correct syntax the modifier stack only updated AFTER I clicked off the object, and back on again. This was the underlying issue, as I had been using the correct syntax previously and copied it incorrectly above.

Comment: @QuarantinedMarsh you can use `obj.data.update()` after you've changed the modifier to show the changes!